# systemd php script output only to systemctl status

Tags: php, systemd, systemctl

i'm trying to run a php script 24/7 with systemd. the terminal output of the script is normally irrelevant so i set 'StandardOutput=0' and 'StandardError=0' to not mess logfiles with gigabytes of data.

but it were great to see both when i from time to time use:

```
sudo systemctl status xyz.service
```

i found no way to accomplish this - that's what i have:

```
[Unit]
Description=xyz.php

[Service]
ExecStart=/xyz.php
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: This is a better question for [Server Fault](//serverfault.com)

Comment: ok - thanx - i've posted the question there now too